# Change the order of tracks in an embed spotify playlist

Tags: embed, spotify, playlist

on my facebook I have a embed player of spotify and this works fine but the order of the play-list is not right, the oldest tracks are at the top and the newest at the bottom. Is there an option to change this the other way round?

I'll hope to receive an answer from you.
Thanks in advance.

With kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

The Play Button widget shows tracks in the canonical order of the playlist, and does *not* respect any custom sorting you've applied in the desktop client. To see this canonical order in the desktop client, click the sorted column header until it's no longer hightlighted in white.